# Right way to handle parallel API calls in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, future, executor

I have a web application in Java where as part of client HTTP request handling, I need to make 2 API calls. The way I am planning to implement is to offload 1 API call to thread pool and do the other call in the same thread and then combine the result. 
I want to process API1 call in parallel but don't want to block it in queue. Hence if no threads available, I am doing it sequentially.
This is what I have come up with.

```
//this is already created in setup, just listing here for reference.
ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 2, 300, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>());
.....


private Future<Integer> getDataFromAPI1(ThreadPoolExecutor tpe){
    try {
        return tpe.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call() throws Exception {
                //....make API call here
                return 1; //return result
            }
        });
    }catch (RejectedExecutionException r){
        //do sequentially and throw any exception encountered
        ///.....

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(1); //return the result
    }
}
public Integer handle(String reqStub){

    Future<Integer> f1 = getDataFromAPI1(tpe);

    //make API call2 here in same thread
    //... this populates r2

    Integer r1 = f1.get();

    //now return final result based on 2 results
    return r1+r2;
}
```

Assume that exception handling is done by caller of handle() method.
Does the code snippet look good in terms of correctness and performance.
Are there better ways of achieving the same?

Comment: "do sequentially and throw any exception encountered" is wrong. Instead of throwing an exception, it should return `new CompletableFuture().completeExceptionally(exception)`, to be on par with asynchronous variant.

Comment: Does order of result matter here?